# java not running into loop

Tags: java, loops

I am writing a program for a java course in university, which reverses a given input of integer. The first loop runs fine, however for some reason the second loop does not even begin and the program is hanging. I am not sure why this is happening and perhaps someone else has an answer. We were told to store the values in variables of type long, and not to store in strings. Thanks.
`

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); //For user input
    long number = 0L; //Where the number entered by the user will be stored
    long loopNumber = 0L; //To be able to control the loop more effectively. a do while loop just kept going forever for some reason
    int nbDigits = 0; //Where the total number of digits will be stored
    long reverse = 0L;//Where the reversed number will be stored


    System.out.println("Enter a number with at most 10 digits:");
        number = keyboard.nextInt();
     keyboard.close(); //Close the Scanner object


    //Counting the total number of digits in the number
    loopNumber = number;
    while(loopNumber != 0) {
        loopNumber /= 10;
        ++nbDigits;
        System.out.println("this is the value of nbDigits " +nbDigits );
    }
    //calculating the reverse order of the entered integer
    loopNumber = number;
    while(loopNumber != 0) {
        reverse *= 10;
        reverse = reverse + (number%10);
    }

    System.out.println("Number of digits is " + nbDigits +"\nReverse of " + number + " is " + reverse);
```

Comment: While the code you posted is not a [mcve], I'm guessing that `keyboard = new Scanner(System.in)` in which case you shouldn't `close()` it.

Comment: The second loop condition depends on the loopNumber variable which never modified within the loop. Reverse in the loop grows forever, put a print line there to see how reverse grows.

Comment: @locke I'm sorry that was a good edit. I just did not notice it until I had done the same thing. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never modify `loopNumber` in the second loop so it will never end.

```java
//calculating the reverse order of the entered integer
loopNumber = number;
while(loopNumber != 0) {
    reverse *= 10;
    reverse = reverse + (number%10);
}
```

Comment: That is for sure the issue. I think I agree with your choice to answer the question asked but leave it for the author to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you! Completely missed that! Probably the easiest solution here

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // For user input
        long number = 0L; // Where the number entered by the user will be stored
        long loopNumber = 0L; // To be able to control the loop more effectively. a do while loop just kept
                                // going forever for some reason
        int nbDigits = 0; // Where the total number of digits will be stored
        long reverse = 0L;// Where the reversed number will be stored

        System.out.println("Enter a number with at most 10 digits:");
        number = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.close(); // Close the Scanner object

        // Counting the total number of digits in the number
        loopNumber = number;
        while (loopNumber != 0) {
            loopNumber /= 10;
            ++nbDigits;
        }
        // calculating the reverse order of the entered integer
        loopNumber = number;
        int loopDigits = nbDigits;
        while (loopDigits != 0) {
            loopDigits--;
            long orig = loopNumber;
            loopNumber /= 10;
            reverse = (long) (reverse + (orig - loopNumber * 10) * Math.pow(10, loopDigits));
        }

        System.out.println("Number of digits is " + nbDigits + "\nReverse of " + number + " is: " + reverse);
    }
}
```

Here are sample input/output

```
Enter a number with at most 10 digits:789456
Number of digits is 6
Reverse of 789456 is: 654987
```